# How to configure logger level to FINEST for Wildfly Swarm

Tags: java, logging, configuration, wildfly, wildfly-swarm

I have followed [this](https://wildfly-swarm.gitbooks.io/wildfly-swarm-users-guide/content/configuration/project_stages.html) guide for project*.yml.

I created two files under **src/main/resources**:

**project-default.yml** which contains:

```
logger:
  level: INFO
swarm:
  http:
    port: 80
```

and **project-dev.yml** which contains:

```
logger:
  level: FINEST
swarm:
  http:
    port: 8080
```

I have successfully switched between them by using the flagg *-Dswarm.project.stage=dev*, verifying that the port is actually changed.

By some reason when using the **dev**-profile the application refuses to logg anything logged with logger.finest(...) while when using logger.info(...) it is logged correctly.

Did I configure the logging levels incorrectly? In that case, how should they be configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
logger:
  level: WHATEVER
```

For logging, Wildfly Swarm relies on the `logging` WildFly subsystem, similarly to other functionalities. So the correct YAML snippet is:

```
swarm:
  logging:
    ...
```

For example:

```
swarm:
  logging:
    root-logger:
      level: FINE
```

Comment: Thanks! Got it to work now. Seems the information in my link was wrong.

Comment: That's an old documentation site. The documentation is currently undergoing refactoring, it should all be eventually available at http://docs.wildfly-swarm.io/, including the reference for configuring fractions. Specifically for logging: http://docs.wildfly-swarm.io/2017.12.1/#_logging_2